# Download file with same pattern

Tags: linux, macos, wget, curl

I have links like these:

```
https://website.com/CODE2016-DEO87.mp4
https://website.com/CODE2016-SX798.mp4
https://website.com/CODE2016-ED082.mp4
```

Do you know a way to download all the files using *wget*, *curl* or anything?

I want to download all the files by running a single command like this one:

`$ wget https://website.com/CODE2016-*.mp4`

Any help?

Comment: Please let me know if I understand correctly: You want to automatically download every possible combination matching `https://website.com/CODE2016-[A-Z0-9]{5}.mp4` ?

Comment: Yup, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by adding ALL files to a list (*.txt file) and using -i option like this:

```
$ wget -i url_list.txt
```

The url_list.txt consists of

```
https://website.com/CODE2016-DEO87.mp4
https://website.com/CODE2016-SX798.mp4
https://website.com/CODE2016-ED082.mp4
```

Comment: I know how to do this, but what if I have other file in that directory with the same pattern which I didnt know the link?

Comment: Take a look: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117988/wget-with-wildcards-in-http-downloads